Different subplot sizes in matplotlib/seaborn
I would like to create a figure with 3x3 plots (heatmaps), the width is the same for all 9 plots. The height, however, should be different for each plot as the height should be number_of_cells_of heatplot*cell_height. Now I can make each row in my figure have a different height but cannot change the height of the subplots within a row. I attached a screenshot to make it clearer, I would just like the cells of all heatplot to have the same height, then that will mean e.g. the subplot in the first row and 2nd column would be just one row.
This is my code so far
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import gridspec

groups = ['g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4', 'g5', 'g6', 'g7', 'g8', 'g9']

dummy_data = {
    'names':['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3', 'name_4', 'name_5', 'name_6', 'name_7', 'name_8', 'name_9', 'name_10', 'name_11', 'name_12', 'name_13', 'name_14', 'name_15', 'name_16', 'name_17', 'name_18', 'name_19', 'name_20']
,
    'group': [
        'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g3', 'g3', 'g4', 'g4',
        'g5', 'g5', 'g6', 'g6', 'g7', 'g7', 'g8', 'g9', 'g9', 'g9'
    ],
    'col1': [
        -30, 10, 5, -20, 15, 25, -15, 0, -10, 20,
        -5, 15, 35, -25, 10, 5, -15, 30, 10, -5
    ],
    'col2': [
        -50, 20, 30, -40, 25, 45, -10, 5, -15, 35,
        -10, 20, 40, -20, 15, 10, -20, 45, 20, -10
    ],
    'col3': [
        -45, 15, 35, -35, 20, 40, -5, 10, -10, 30,
        -15, 25, 45, -15, 12, 7, -18, 40, 25, -8
    ],
    'col4': [
        0.05, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, 0.09, 0.11, 0.05, 0.08, 0.07, 0.10,
        0.04, 0.09, 0.12, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.06, 0.11, 0.05, 0.09
    ],
    'col5': [
        0.12, 0.07, 0.09, 0.04, 0.08, 0.10, 0.06, 0.09, 0.05, 0.11,
        0.03, 0.10, 0.13, 0.07, 0.06, 0.07, 0.05, 0.10, 0.04, 0.08
    ],
    'col6': [
        20, 25, 15, 30, 40, 10, 35, 5, 45, 25,
        10, 20, 50, 15, 30, 25, 40, 15, 10, 35
    ],
    'col7': [
        45, 15, 25, 10, 30, 40, 20, 35, 5, 20,
        30, 15, 40, 20, 10, 15, 50, 30, 5, 25
    ],
    'col8': [
        5, 2, 8, 3, 7, 6, 4, 9, 1, 8,
        6, 3, 10, 2, 7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 8
    ],
    'col9': [
        6, 3, 9, 4, 8, 7, 5, 10, 2, 9,
        7, 4, 10, 3, 8, 5, 9, 6, 3, 9
    ]
}

pivot_df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data)

# Define column bounds with new names
column_bounds = {
    'col1': (-35, 35),
    'col2': (-55, 55),
    'col3': (-50, 50),
    'col4': (0.03, 0.15),
    'col5': (0.03, 0.15),
    'col6': (0, 50),
    'col7': (0, 50),
    'col8': (0, 10),
    'col9': (0, 10),
}

# Calculate row counts for each group
row_counts = [len(pivot_df.loc[pivot_df['group'] == group]) for group in groups]

# Calculate height ratios based on the row count for each group to ensure each cell has the same height
cell_height = 0.5  # Set a fixed cell height
height_ratios = [count * cell_height for count in row_counts]

# Create the figure and GridSpec with proportional height ratios for each subplot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(32, 21))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3, height_ratios=[max(height_ratios[:3]), max(height_ratios[3:6]), max(height_ratios[6:])])

# Add subplots to the grid
axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[i // 3, i % 3]) for i in range(9)]

for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    # Get the data for the current group
    group_data = pivot_df.loc[pivot_df['group'] == group].set_index('names').drop(columns={'group'})

    # Create annotation array
    annotations = group_data.copy()
    for col in ['col6', 'col7', 'col8', 'col9']:
        annotations[col] = annotations[col].apply(lambda x: f"{x:.2f}M")
    for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']:
        annotations[col] = annotations[col].apply(lambda x: f"{x:.2f}")
    
    # Plot each column individually with separate bounds
    for j, col in enumerate(group_data.columns):
        # Create a mask for other columns to plot each individually
        mask = np.ones(group_data.shape)
        mask[:, j] = 0  # Mask all except the current column
       
        sns.heatmap(
            group_data,
            annot=annotations,
            fmt='',
            cmap="coolwarm",
            cbar=False,
            vmin=column_bounds[col][0], 
            vmax=column_bounds[col][1],
            mask=mask, 
            ax=axes[i]
        )

    axes[i].set_title(group)
    axes[i].set_ylabel('')

    # Rotate y-tick labels to be horizontal if there are any labels
    yticklabels = group_data.index.tolist()
    axes[i].set_yticks(np.arange(len(group_data)))  # Set tick positions based on number of rows
    axes[i].set_yticklabels(yticklabels, rotation=0, ha='right', fontsize=8)

    if i < 6:  # Only for the top two rows (0–5), remove x labels and ticks
        axes[i].set_xlabel('')
        axes[i].set_xticks([])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.2)

plt.show()

-

Maybe you could try to add axes[i].set_aspect(1.5) which would set the same aspect ratio for each cell.

If you can set sharey = True, the y-axes per row will be on the same scale

You might try to define a bigger GridSpec grid (say the total number of cells high you need in a column), then have subplots span multiple rows. For example, the top left subplots would span 4 rows, the top middle would span 1 row, and the top right would span 3 rows, etc.
